# DateLastModified (ASP) and Excel files + ASP compilation

Tags: excel, properties, asp-classic

I'm trying to get the last modified date of an Excel file. 
I've been looking around and I stitched up pieces and pieces until I got to this:

```
<%
 dim fs,f
 set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 set f=fs.GetFile("c:\test.txt")
 Response.Write("<h3>File last modified on: ")
 Response.Write(f.DateLastModified)
 Response.Write("</h3>")
 set f=nothing
 set fs=nothing
 %>
```

Now, the problems:

1) I read another question here regarding the use of the DateLastModified property with Excel files (the person had the problem that oftentimes the last modified date was before the creation date of the file), so I'm wondering: does DateLastModified return the expected results if the file is an .xlsx?

2) Is there any possibility of compiling ASP online, without having to buy or install anything? I couldn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting the proper date returned, then it's working! there are no "special cases" with file types in ASP,

if you're looking for a place online where you can run online asp snippets (similar to jsFiddle for javascript), I haven't come across anything. But to get it setup to run locally, all you need is IIS, as classic asp is included for free as a feature in IIS, all you need to do is switch it on.